# Role of path connectedness in fundamental group of product space

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

Proposition 1.12 from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book states that
\begin{align*}
\pi_1(X \times Y) \; \text{is isomorphic to} \; \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y) \; \text{if X and Y are path connected} \; 
\end{align*}
I tried to understand the proof but I fail to see where the condition of path connectedness is needed, aside from the fact that one had to fix a base point otherwise. So I guess my question is:

Is $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_o,y_0))$ isomorphic to  $\pi_1(X,x_0) \times \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ even for spaces that are not path connected? If not, why not and is there an easy counter example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just that one usually uses the fundamental group on path connected spaces. It surely works even in the non path connected case, by simply passing to the path connected component of the base point.

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes and the proof is very easy. The answer to "why mention path connectedness ?" is that $\pi_1(X)$ is the isomorphism class of all the $\pi_1(X,x_0), x_0\in X$ but it's not well defined if $X$ is not path-connected, as  $\pi_1(X,x)$ and $\pi_1(X,y)$ need not be isomorphic if $X$ is not path connected

Comment: @Max okay I think I understand thank you. Part of the confusion was arising because I also saw the statement in my topology lecture, but with the base points explicitly included, and there the path connectedness was also mentioned. Just seemed weird, thank you guys.

Comment: If $\pi_1(X)$ denotes the fundamental groupoid then the canonical morphism $\pi_1(X \times Y) \to \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y)$ is indeed an isomorphism for all spaces $X,Y$.